# Nesting foreach state

Tags: powershell

I have the following script to list the running vms on hyper-V servers:

```
$VirtualHosts = Get-content "C:\scripts\Hosts.txt"
ForEach ($Guest in $VirtualHosts)
{Get-VM -ComputerName $Guest | Where State -eq Running | FT Name}
```

I want to add the functionality of rebooting the computers using the `Restart-Computer` cmdlet.  To do this, I plan on using a nested foreach statement.  Can you help me with the nested statement?

Answer (score 2):

Nesting two loop constructs is pretty straight-forward in PowerShell - just make sure the inner/nested loop is entirely contained within the body of the outer loop:

```
$VirtualHosts = Get-content "C:\scripts\Hosts.txt"

foreach($vHost in $VirtualHosts)
{
    foreach($runningVM in Get-VM -ComputerName $vHost | Where State -eq Running)
    {
        $runningVM |Restart-VM
    }
}
```

You can also skip the inner loop completely and just pipe the output from `Get-VM` directly to `Restart-VM`:

```
foreach($vHost in $VirtualHosts)
{
    Get-VM -ComputerName $vHost | Where State -eq Running | Restart-VM
}
```

Comment: You can even remove the outer loop, as `Get-VM` parameter `-ComputerName` accepts an array: `Get-VM -ComputerName $VirtualHosts | Where State -eq Running | Restart-VM`